# Proving that a sequence converges using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I don't know how to prove this:

$$\frac{n^2}{5n + 1} \to \infty \text{ when } n \to \infty.$$

This is the hint my teacher gave:

> According to the definition of convergence, given $K$, we have to find $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, then $n^2/(5n + 1) > K$. However, if $n> 0$,  $n^2/(5n + 1) < n^2/5n = n/5$.

**Now can you find a value of $N$ such that $n^2 / (5n + 1)> 5$?**     I don't get the last part why should we find such an $N$?

Comment: Use: $n²/(5n + 1) >n²/6n $.

Comment: You need to prove that for every large  M >0 your sequence is great than this M. It’s almost trivial. Your professor just want you to know how to use the definition of divergence.

Comment: I think your teacher got mixed up in the hint they gave. You want to use something like $n^2/(5n+1)>\ldots$ and not $n^2/(5n+1)<\ldots$.

Comment: Your logic is messed up. You need implications in  the reverse order. @MarkViola

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $$\frac{n^2}{5n+1}>K\iff n>N_1=5K/2+\sqrt{K+(25K^2/4)}$$with bilateral logic.  Alternatively, $$\frac{n^2}{5n+1}<\frac{n}{6}<K \Leftarrow n>N_2=6K$$suffices.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thank you everyone